# Summary method results do not seem to be accurate for vectors

Tags: r

This is puzzling me. When you run summary() on a vector of integers you don't seem to get accurate results. The numbers seem to be rounded off. I tried this on three different machines with different OS's and the results are the same.

For a vector:

```
>a <- 0:628846
>str(a)
 int [1:628847] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
>summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0  157200  314400  314400  471600  628800 
>max(a)
[1] 628846
```

For a data.frame:

```
> b <- data.frame(b = 0:628846)
> str(b)
'data.frame':   628847 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ b: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
> summary(b)
       b         
 Min.   :     0  
 1st Qu.:157212  
 Median :314423  
 Mean   :314423  
 3rd Qu.:471635  
 Max.   :628846  
> summary(b$b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0  157200  314400  314400  471600  628800
```

Why are these results different?

Comment: @kohske ok, that works. Does that mean that the default summary method for vectors is different than for data.frames?

Comment: @wahalulu Try `methods(summary)` and you'll see that data.frames have the `summary.data.frame` method run on them but numerics wind up in `summary.default`.

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Precision-of-summary-when-summarizing-variables-in-a-data-frame-td3428570.html (there are probably other discussions of this out there elsewhere)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correcting "summary" in R with appropriate # of digits of precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840073/correcting-summary-in-r-with-appropriate-of-digits-of-precision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `a` is class `integer`, `b` is class `data.frame`.  A `data frame` is a `list` with certain properties and with class `data.frame` (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames).  Many functions, including `summary`, handle objects of different classes differently (see that you can use `summary` on an object of class `lm` and it gives you something completely different).  If you want to apply the function `summary` to every components in `b`, you could use `lapply`:

```
> a <- 0:628846
> b <- data.frame(b = 0:628846)
> class(a)
[1] "integer"
> class(b)
[1] "data.frame"
> names(b)
[1] "b"
> length(b)
[1] 1
> summary(b[[1]]) # b[[1]] gives the first component of the list b
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0  157200  314400  314400  471600  628800 
> class(b$b)
[1] "integer"
> summary(b$b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0  157200  314400  314400  471600  628800 
> lapply(b,summary)
$b
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0  157200  314400  314400  471600  628800 
> 
> # example of summary on a linear model
> x <- rnorm(100)
> y <- x + rnorm(100)
> my.lm <- lm(y~x)
> class(my.lm)
[1] "lm"
> summary(my.lm)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6847 -0.5460  0.1175  0.6610  2.2976 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.04122    0.09736   0.423    0.673    
x            1.14790    0.09514  12.066   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.9735 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.5977, Adjusted R-squared: 0.5936 
F-statistic: 145.6 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```