# un-intersect values in R

Tags: r, intersection

I have two data sets of at least 420,500 observations each, e.g.

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(col1=c("microsoft","apple","vmware","delta","microsoft"),
                     col2=paste0(c("a","b","c",4,"asd"),".exe"),
                     col3=rnorm(5))

dataset2 <- data.frame(col1=c("apple","cisco","proactive","dtex","microsoft"),
                     col2=paste0(c("a","b","c",4,"asd"),".exe"),
                     col3=rnorm(5))
> dataset1
       col1    col2 col3
1 microsoft   a.exe    2
2     apple   b.exe    1
3    vmware   c.exe    3
4     delta   4.exe    4
5 microsoft asd.exe    5
> dataset2
       col1    col2 col3
1     apple   a.exe    3
2     cisco   b.exe    4
3    vmware   d.exe    1
4     delta   5.exe    5
5 microsoft asd.exe    2
```

I would like to print all the observations in `dataset1` that ***do not*** intersect one in `dataset2` (comparing both `col1` and `col2` in each), which in this case would print everything except the last observation - observations 1 & 2 match on `col2` but not `col1` and observation 3 & 4 match on `col1` but not `col2`, i.e.:

```
        col1  col2 col3 
1:     apple b.exe    1 
2:     delta 4.exe    4 
3: microsoft a.exe    2 
4:    vmware c.exe    3
```

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr); anti_join(df1, df2, by='col2')`

Comment: I need entire observations to be printed. not just the values.

Comment: @vardha Based on the example you showed, both the datasets have the same elements for col2, so the expected output will be 0 rows

Comment: sorry . my bad.. I need to compare both col1 and col2 and print remaining observations.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('col1', 'col2'))
 #      col1  col2       col3
 #1     delta 4.exe -0.5836272
 #2    vmware c.exe  0.4196231
 #3     apple b.exe  0.5365853
 #4 microsoft a.exe -0.5458808
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('microsoft', 'apple', 'vmware', 'delta', 
 'microsoft'), col2= c('a.exe', 'b.exe', 'c.exe', '4.exe', 'asd.exe'), 
    col3=rnorm(5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 set.seed(22)
 df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c( 'apple', 'cisco', 'proactive', 'dtex', 
 'microsoft'), col2= c('a.exe', 'b.exe', 'c.exe', '4.exe', 'asd.exe'), 
  col3=rnorm(5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` solution [inspired by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319083/how-do-i-do-a-negative-nomatch-inverse-search-in-data-table):

```
library(data.table) #1.9.5+
setDT(dataset1,key=c("col1","col2"))
setDT(dataset2,key=key(dataset1))
dataset1[!dataset2]

        col1  col2 col3
1:     apple b.exe    1
2:     delta 4.exe    4
3: microsoft a.exe    2
4:    vmware c.exe    3
```

You could also try without keying:

```
library(data.table) #1.9.5+
setDT(dataset1); setDT(dataset2)
dataset1[!dataset2,on=c("col1","col2")]
```

Comment: No reason to keep the inferior variant around, eh?